# Cocos2dx error compile using XCode

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x

I just download new Cocos2d-x version 2.1.5. And try the new feature by generate project for all platform by calling "create_project.py".
All project platform created successfully, and try Android and windows platform and it works properly.
But i have an error when running on my XCode. Here the error i got 
[image]
Please let me know if anyone know how to fix it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It will be better to add the error image directly in here than putting up a link to that.

Comment: Thank you RinoTom. But i need to have at least 10 reputation to make it. :)

Comment: Is there an error above that one? Exit code 1 is just the exit code, usually you'll find the actual error above. PS: when you're in the build log view, just hit Cmd+C to copy the contents as text.

Comment: That was all error i have. Nothing else.
The Error was the one with red block. And the text above you can find it above it. :)
FYI, i use XCode 4.2.1.